# What was the purpose of the turbo button?

Tags: gaming, clockspeed

What did the turbo button on old PCs do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [turbo button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button) article:

> The button was generally present on older systems, and was designed to allow the user to play older games that depended on processor speed for their timing.

Older games often would run programs as fast as the processor allowed. Since the developer designed the game for a 33MHz processor, as long as the user had a 33MHz processor, everything functioned as designed.  Once the user upgraded to a 66MHz processor, though, the game now ran twice as fast, making it unplayable.  The turbo button would slow the computer down to deal with this effect.

Comment: so 'turbo' was really 'slowmo' ? I can't remember if ours was always on (depressed) or not... :-?

Comment: Yes. There was no reason to turn off turbo unless your program was running unusably fast.

Answer (score 2):

It would switch the processor between 4.77Mhz (the stock speed for an IBM XT) and whatever faster speed the processor was capable of - often 8Mhz. My hunch is that it was switching between two different crystals on the motherboard, but I don't have an old XT mobo lying around to follow the traces to be sure.

Comment: Actually the Turbo button was also present on some AT boards.

Comment: True. My 386SX-16 could unturbo from 16MHz to 8MHz.

Answer (score 0):

*Nice picture, it depicts exactly the same casing I had on my 386DX :)*

[Stolen from Wikipedia]

> [**The turbo button**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button) changes the effective speed of the system.
>   It usually accomplishes this by either adjusting the CPU clock speed
>   directly, or by turning off the processor's cache, forcing it to wait
>   on slow main memory every time. The button was generally present on
>   older systems, and was designed to allow the user to play older games
>   that depended on processor speed for their timing. Systems could also
>   use the keyboard combination of ctrl-alt-+/-, '-' switching turbo off
>   and '+' switching it on (ctrl-alt-\ to toggle between turbo/normal
>   mode on ITT Xtra machines). Of course, calling it a "turbo" button
>   when its function slows the system down can be a bit misleading, but
>   the button was usually set up so the system would be at full speed
>   when the button was "on". The turbo button was often linked to a MHz
>   LED display on the system case, or to a "hi"/"lo" LED display. While
>   the implementation of the turbo button by manufacturers has all but
>   disappeared, Software Developers have compensated with software
>   replacements. One example is DOSBox, which offers full turbo button
>   functionality. Some modern PCs that support ACPI power management
>   provide an on-screen control for the user to switch a PC's performance
>   state between low- and high- performance modes.